# Understanding {{.0}} {{.1}} in stache templates

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

I'm working on a project with stache (a version of mustache, the templating system) and I've come across

```
<a href="{{.0}}" data-set="{{.1}}"></a>
```

If I was guessing, I'd say that those numbers are indexes in an array? But I'm not sure and I can't find a reference to them in the docs...

Do you know what they are?

Help greatly appreciated...

James

Comment: How about looking at the output, and the view data, and just determining what's happening from that?

Comment: Hi Cerberus,
I did. It obviously outputs the href, and attributes, etc. I'm new to the project and it's monolithic and badly coded, so I'm trying to work out where the data comes from and how it's interpreted.

I just don't know what that syntax means and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction...

{{.}} outputs an object, probably the context you're in, but {{.0}} outputs nothing when I mocked it up...

Comment: You have to work out the context from the surrounding tags, I.e. {{#person}}{{.0}}{{/person}} should be a reference to person[0] or iterating person[i][0] for every i. (I think it could be either depending on whether person is a real array or an object/arguments? with numbered indexes.)

Comment: @lossleader Yes, I agree. Trouble is, that's the only line inside a partial file who's parents aren't that obvious - so context is a problem.

I can't get that syntax to work in isolation either:

var james = ["james", 36],

or james = {name: "james", age: 36},

or james = {1: "james", 2: 36};

or james = [{name: "james"}, {age: 36}];

when template is <p>{{.0}}</p><p>{{.1}}</p>

can.view.render(template, james) <-- renders nothing in the els.

Comment: @user1775718 so add <!-- {{.}} --> and find out.. I don't understand what your question for us is.

Comment: @lossleader The question is "What does the {{.0}} syntax do in mustache?"

Is {{.0}} an index for an object, collection, or array? What does putting a dot followed by a number actually do?

Comment: @user1775718 and the answer is it is the property labeled 0 in the context you are in. But that doesn't tell you anything about whether the context is {0:blah} or [blah].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely this:

https://github.com/mustache/spec/issues/52

That's an extension to the Mustache spec that allows anchoring tag names to the current context, basically combining the `{{.}}` tag with dot notation.

Comment: Yes, to anybody that has this question, {{.1}} is actually for an object with a property named 1. Unbelievably there are programmers out there who are that bad...

Comment: Was it actually referencing the 1th element of an array? Lots of mustache implementations (e.g. javascript, php) allow that.

Comment: The people in question had stored a set of tabs as an array, and within that each tab was an array. The values were manually entered for each tab attribute as above, then tabs were picked by index using _.at().

So it looked like [ ['#', '', '/en/blah', true] [...] ]. and each array was parsed into the template {{.0}} returns the hash, {{.2}} the '/en/blah', etc.

Works, but not very readable, maintainable - rather error prone and not object oriented.

Comment: Yeah, that's really ugly. Also, that's a perfect example of someone not doing a good job of preparing their view model :)